# C# snapshot logfile

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I was wondering how to create a logfile like the `/proc/*` files found on Unix like systems.

I'm on windows in .Net C#.

I have a service which uses log4net and have a normal logfile for logging events. What i would like is a file that i could copy or read that would give me a snapshot of the current state of the service. The service would update the data every few seconds.

The file I would imagine would be some kind of memory mapped file like those used for IPC. It would get truncated every update and rewritten with various information. The file would not need to be persisted.

Do anyone have any experience with this sort of logging/tracing? Are there any framework that provide this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no such standard in windows, you can basically make your own.

You can write a file (and truncate it however you like) to any accessible location you find fit. You can create a monitoring application that directly communicates with your service (RPC / sockets / pipes / ...) and displays relevant information...

I'm sure you could think of other alternatives as well, but the point is, no matter what you choose, it will be proprietary, and will be used solely by your service.

Comment: Thank you. I went with a memory mapped physical file and it works great as a realtime non persistent logfile showing a snapshot of the application state.

Comment: Great! that's a very simple solution to implement. good choice.